# Magento: get block of product view

Tags: magento

I instanciate the following block by using the operator new but when I am going to use getProduct() it does not return anything because it doesn't have the ID of the product. How can I add it?

```
$block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
```